# Accepting two offers for PhD in USA before April 15th

Tags: phd, united-states, visa

Suppose I accept two offers before April 15th and then get two I-20s issued. It is up to me to choose the one university I want to go to and I am the one who has to complete the SEVIS formalities by mentioning the SEVIS ID issued in one of the I-20s, so from a legal standpoint, no one can stop my visa, right?

Comment: Yes, it is up to you to choose which one to go to, but you do that before April 15. As for visas, I don’t see how not choosing now helps with anything.

Comment: But both univs sent me offers within 2 days of April 15th and both offers bring with them different perks including stipend amount and University outreach. It was difficult for me to make a decision so fast and I accepted both however by the time the i20 comes (I am an international student) I would have made up my mind and would politely decline one of the offers

Comment: I had been inquiring the univs for a long time and they took very long to give an offer

Comment: Well, that was a very rude thing to do. Somebody else may not get in to one of them because of you. You didn’t do your homework ahead of time to know which one to choose under what circumstances.

Comment: I was not aware of details such as stipend amount

Comment: Plus the second offer came on 13th of April literally 2 days before deadline

Comment: So, how many days would it have taken you to make a decision? Two days is a lot of thinking time. You are rationalizing bad behavior that impacts at least one other person. Yes, you didn't know details - so in the future you think through the pros and cons, and figure what it would take to choose one or the other offer, should one be made. You had months and months to be thinking through which offer(s) would be attractive for what reasons.

Answer (score 9):

I would not recommend to accept two offers and then later tell them "Oh, sorry guys I didn't mean it". This will certainly create bad blood and academia is in certain fields like a small village. In the worst case the other university could then withdraw their offer and you will not have either one.

Choose the offer that fits you better and behave honestly.